# Unsupported operand types

Tags: php, arrays, math

I am working on a shopping cart function for a website and have stumbled across this error:

**Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in ... on line xx**

I think this may be because I am performing some math between a variable and a value within an array. What I am not sure of is how to perform math on a value within an array:

```php
$line_cost = $price * $quantity;
```

Can anyone give me any guidance on this please? I will be most grateful! Here is the relevant code -

```php
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
    
  $product_id = $_GET['id'];     
  $action     = $_GET['action'];
    
  switch($action) {
    case "add":
      $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;
      break;
  }
        
?>
    
<?php   
  foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantity) {  
    list($name, $description, $price) = getProductInfo($product_id);
                    
    echo "$price"; // 20
    var_dump($quantity); // "array(2) { ["productid"]=> string(1) "2" ["qty"]=> int(1) }". 
                    
    $line_cost = $price * $quantity;  //Fatal error occurs here

  }
?>
```

Comment: Is `$line_cost = $price * $quantity` the content of line 77?

Comment: It means your two *operands* are not numbers or anything that can be converted to numbers. What are the two variables?!

Comment: You've got a bunch of SQL injection problems here. You should read http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @Michael Walkling use the function `gettype()` and find out the datatypes of `$price` and `$quantity` and let us know!

Comment: I can see `var_dump($quantity);` in the code. What is the output?

Comment: By giving this code a good read, I think that the error may be how you store the quantity of the products in the session variable in another PHP file? Perhaps you store it as: `$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]['quantity'] = 1` A mistake like that can be easily made

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Sorry for the delay in responding. Line 77 is "$line_cost = $price * $quantity;" echo from $price is "20" and Var_dump from $quantity is "array(2) { ["productid"]=> string(1) "2" ["qty"]=> int(1) }". What I am trying to do is multiply the quantity by the price

Comment: Thanks for the SQL injection problems link!

Comment: I have performed the gettype command. $price is a string. $quantity is an array.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As the `gettype()` function shows that `$price` is a string and `$quantity` is an array, typecast `$price` first to integer and use the array `$quantity` with its key to access the integer value (if it is not an integer, typecast it too).

So it goes like:

```
$line_cost =(int)$price * (int)$quantity['key'];
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat. my issue was the same output but coming from a WordPress integration problem between the plugin ELEX and the plugin woocommerce product bundles. ELEX never once defined the data type of variables it deals with. Thanks again (added the comment so others that have the same problem can find this solution)

Comment: for future readers, note that depending on the case, the casting should be to FLOAT instead of INT, otherwise they may loose precision. In this case, since it's a price, I would expect it to have cents (or whatever, depending on currency)

Answer (score 1):

> I think this may be because I am performing some math between a variable and a value within an array.

Not quite.

You are attempting to perform math (multiplication) between an integer **and** an array, eg: 20 x array.  This doesn’t work because array’s don’t have a multiplication operand (and if they did, it probably wouldn’t do what you want).

What you **want** to do is to perform math on an variable and a value (element) within an array.  Since your array is an associative array, you need to supply the key, like so:

```
$line_cost = $price * $quantity['qty'];
```