# PHP - Average input form with value in database error Unsupported operand types

Tags: php, average

I want to average the value from **input form price** with **price from database**.

so I tried to edit my code like this :

```
//input form
$productName=$_POST['productName'];
$buyingPrice=$_POST['buyingPrice'];
$sql2="SELECT product_name FROM products WHERE product_name='$productName'";
$result2=mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);

//process to average
if($result2=true){
    $sql2="SELECT buying_price FROM products WHERE product_name='$productName'";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);
    $beli = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $beli_new=$_POST['buyingPrice'];
    $ratabeli=$beli+$beli_new/2; //I get the error on this line
    $sql = "UPDATE products SET buying_price='$ratabeli' WHERE product_name='$productName'";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Stok $productName dirata-ratakan!');</script>";
}
```

reference [from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122419/unsupported-operand-types), I've add this code `$ratabeli=(int)$beli+(int)$beli_new/2;`

but the average isn't working, and my data just output first price,

Can anyone give me any guidance on this case please

Comment: $result2=true  is assigning value true to $result2 ..comparison should be ==

Comment: use like this $ratabeli=($beli+$beli_new)/2;

Comment: @JYoThI thanks for the suggest sir, i've edit the code, but the error still shown, i dunno how to fix it,

Comment: $beli is array you need to extract the value from it

Comment: @JYoThI when i tried this code `die(var_dump("$beli")` this is an array, but i can't fix it

Comment: @JYoThI can you give me a reference how to convert/extract the array?

Comment: $ratabeli=($beli['buyingPrice']+$beli_new)/2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `$result2=true` is assigning value true to `$result2` .comparison should be`==`  or `===`

2) `$beli` is array you need to extract the value from it.

use like this

```
$ratabeli=($beli['buyingPrice']+$beli_new)/2;
```

> #### Much care your code looks. sql injection possibilities .try to use prepared statement or PDO

Comment: your code look's work, and when i use `die(var_dump($ratabeli));`  the output is `int(7000)` but the database won't **update**, what happened? should i extract the `int` to `array`?

Comment: you need to execute the query mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

Comment: oh man, you save me, thanks for an idea, i didn't notice about `mysqli_query($connection, $sql);` and sorry i cant up vote ur answer because of my reputation,

Comment: Much care . your code looks. sql injection possibilities .try to use prepared statement or PDO  take care of this @Destiny